# how can I cropout some part of a tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to crop some parts of a tensor and assign these parts with zero. for this aim, I used the following code, but it produces the following error. how can solve this problem? I am using Keras and I have a CNN network. x is the output of the convolution layer and a tensor.
Thanks.

```
def diff_cropout(x, rate=0.6):
    global block_size
    cover_img =x[0]
    Iw = x[1]
    diff = Iw - cover_img
    diff_shape = diff.get_shape().as_list()
    h, w = diff_shape[1:3]

    blacked_pixels = int(rate * (h*w))
    height = int(np.floor(np.sqrt(blacked_pixels)))
    width = int(np.ceil(np.sqrt(blacked_pixels)))

    x = np.random.randint(0, w - width)
    y = np.random.randint(0, h - height)

    new_diff = diff
    new_diff = new_diff[y:y+height, x:x+width].assign(tf.zeros([height, width]))
    new_Iw = cover_img + new_diff

    return new_I
```

in my network:

```
diff_cropout_attacked = layers.Lambda(diff_cropout, arguments={'rate':diff_cropRate}, name='diff_cropout_attack')([image, actimg])
```

the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('E:/New folder/testattack.py',
>   wdir='E:/New folder')
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py",
>   line 704, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py",
>   line 108, in execfile
>       exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "E:/Newfolder/testattack.py", line 319, in 
>       diff_cropout_attacked = layers.Lambda(diff_cropout, arguments={'rate':diff_cropRate},
>   name='residual_cropout_attack')([image, actimg])
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py",
>   line 457, in **call**
>       output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\core.py",
>   line 687, in call
>       return self.function(inputs, **arguments)
>
> File "E:/Newfolder/testattack.py", line 199, in diff_cropout
>       new_diff = new_diff[y:y+height, x:x+width].assign(tf.zeros([height, width]))
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\array_ops.py",
>   line 700, in assign
>       raise ValueError("Sliced assignment is only supported for variables")
>
> ValueError: Sliced assignment is only supported for variables

Comment: Hello, do  you have any suggestion?